# Is there a way to create a custom report to track page views for certain URLs in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to create a custom report where I can track page views for certain URLs on my website, but struggle to include more than 1 URL. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily doable with a custom report and segments in GA:
You can do the following:

1. Click on Customization
2. Click on Custom Reports
3. Choose Landing Page and any metrics you need
4. Click Save

[image]

Once you've done this, you can set up a segment with conditions:
You can add the names of whichever landing pages you need inside the condition text box.

[image]

Comment: does it matter if I choose "Page" or "Landing Page"?

Comment: Well Landing Page is generally if a user directly lands on this page through an external source (Google, FB, IG etc.) 
And just Page would be if a user is navigating internal website pages e.g from Home to Collections to Product.

Comment: it does. Question: although I selected exact match, but it still shows different URLs in the custom report

Comment: I think I understand what happened. My ultimate goal is to show only the pages I selected in the segment, not any other pages that might get filtered because of the segment that is applied.

Comment: In that case you can put exact match conditions for all the URLs you want and then add a does not match condition for any other URLs.

Comment: I think it's showing other URLs because of the dimension, not the conditions of the segment

Comment: Your dimension can be set to Page if that's what you need. Let me know if that worked.

Comment: sorry for the last response. Adding Page to dimension doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Add screen shots of your segment conditions and dimensions.